# How Do I Update The DOM in AngularJS (1.7.x) in Promise.all() Without $scope?

Tags: angularjs, promise, angularjs-scope, angular-promise

We've been trying to prepare an app at work as much as possible for a future migration from AngularJS to Angular. My understanding is that we are to avoid using $scope as much as possible. However, I'm finding a situation where I'm performing a Promise.all() and I can't figure out how to update the DOM without $scope.$apply(). Here's some pseudo code as an example.

Angular 1.7.x question: How do I get the DOM to render new values when a Promise.all() resolves? Word on the street is we're not supposed to use $scope.$apply(), but that's all I can figure out...

```
export class FooController {

    constructor(FooService, $scope) {
        this.fooService = FooService;
        this.$scope = $scope;
    }

    $onInit() {
        this.data = [];
        this.requests[...]; // holding some requests
        this.updateData();
    }

    updateData() {
        let promises = [];
        this.requests.forEach(i => promises.push(this.fooService.get(i)));

        Promise.all(promises)
            .then(res => {
                this.data = res;
                this.$scope.$apply();
            })
    }
}

FooController.$inject = ['FooService', '$scope'];

export const fooComponent = {
    templateUrl: templateUrl,
    controller: FooController
}
```

Comment: Use $q.all(), and the AngularJS promise will call $scope.$apply for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [$q service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q):

```
export class FooController {

    constructor(FooService, $q) {
        this.fooService = FooService;
        this.$q = $q;
    }

    $onInit() {
        this.data = [...];

        this.updateData();
    }

    updateData() {
        let promises = [];
        this.data.forEach(i => promises.push(this.fooService.get(i)));

        ̶P̶r̶o̶m̶i̶s̶e̶.̶a̶l̶l̶(̶p̶r̶o̶m̶i̶s̶e̶s̶)̶
        this.$q.all(promises)
            .then(res => {
                this.something = res;
                ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶.̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶$̶a̶p̶p̶l̶y̶(̶)̶;̶
            })
    }
}

FooController.$inject = ['FooService', '$q'];

export const fooComponent = {
    templateUrl: templateUrl,
    controller: FooController
}
```

AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

ES6 promises are not integrated with the AngularJS execution context. Instead use promises created by the [$q Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

Answer (score 0):

To use a value in the DOM, this value should be attached to a scope or to a controller. So, you can not change any value in DOM without changing the value of the $scope, or of the controller's property

Comment: I see what you're saying. I didn't type up my pseudo-code very well. It's updated now to show that the result gets set to the controller's `data` property. It still doesn't solve the problem though. AngularJS doesn't digest in a Promise.all(), so even though the property on the controller is set as you say, the DOM doesn't update.